# Conexao da Base de dados ao 000webhost

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, conexão

estou com um problema na conexão ao `000webhost`

O código que tenho é o seguinte:
Penso que esteja bem pois so mudei os valores correspondestes ao localhost

```
<?php

    ob_start();

        $link = mysql_connect('planos.comla.com', 'a9046774_planos', '') or die('Could not con: ' . mysql_error());
    //$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

    mysql_select_db('a9046774_planos') or die('Could not select database: ' . mysql_error());
    mysql_set_charset('utf8');


?>
```

E quando coloco este ficheiro no `000webhost` aparece me esta mensagem de erro

> Could not con: Access denied for user 'a9046774_planos'@'10.1.1.23' (using password: NO)

Comment: Coloca o código e as strings de conexão na pergunta.

Comment: Como assim? 
a que se refere?

Comment: Atualizei minha resposta com um código que achei na internet de uma pessoa informando que conseguiu dessa forma. Muda os dados para o seu caso.

Comment: Coloca o host como `localhost` e também a senha usada para acessar esse servidor.

Answer (score 0):

A maneira correta de se conectar é assim:

```
<?php
$servername = "Localhost"; ***/* LETRA INICIAL MAUIUSCULA*/***
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

Achei esse código na internet, acredito que posso resolver o seu problema. Você não está usando senha e o servername está errado. Veja a senha do seu usuário e coloca o servername assim:

```
$conn = mysql_connect("mysql#.000webhost.com", "a3367xxx_test","******") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: amigo a ajuda é boa
Mas não da certo no meu nao sei porque

Comment: Vc já descobriu sua senha? Acho dificil um banco no servidor não ter senha.

Comment: sim sim 
mas penso que o erro nao seja dai